# echarts: how to remove the xAxis bottom border line and the small vertical lines

Tags: javascript, echarts

Trying to remove this:

[image]

My settings so far based on the [specs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis):

```
 xAxis: {
  type: "category",
  nameGap: 0,
  showGrid: false,
  splitLine: {
    show: false,
  },
  minorSplitLine: {
    show: false,
  },
  lines: {
    show: false,
  },
  axisBorder: {
    show: false,
  },
  axisTicks: {
    show: false,
  },
  minorTick: {
    show: false,
  },
  axisLabel: {
    align: "center",
    show: false,
  },
  boundaryGap: false,
  data: ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
}
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the bottom of the xAxis?
I want to display only the data graphs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove xAxis (line, ticks and label) :

```js
xAxis: {
  axisLine : {
    show: false,
  },
  axisTick : { // Be careful: it's axisTick and not axisTicks
    show: false,
  }, 
  axisLabel : {
    show: false,
  },
},
```